# Benchmarking with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, benchmarking

I'm new to Rails but not new to software development and so some of these may be elementary questions mixed in with head-scratching ones.

We are trying to get some benchmarking in our app and are having some frustrating moments getting Rails, Capybara, and the database to play well together.

We have a database already filled with data, so I decided to start with that. This is the script I wrote to create and db and run the test:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 RAILS_ENV=test

 RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV rake db:drop

 RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV rake db:create

 RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV rake db:migrate

 RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV rake demo:data:load

 RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV  rake test:benchmark
```

This is the simple test that I wrote:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

require 'capybara/rails'

# Profiling results for each test method are written to tmp/performance.
class BrowsingTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest
  def setup
     sign_in "fred"
  end
  def test_dashboard
     get '/dashboard'
     get '/question_collections'
     get '/question_collections/5'
     get '/question_collections/5/questions/60'

     get '/message_collections'

   end

end
```

And I get the following error:

```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in' for 
     test_dashboard(BrowsingTest):BrowsingTest.test/performance/browsing_test.rb:7:in `setup'
```

So it seems that Capybara isn't found, which is odd since we use it in our functional tests quite a bit. Then I rolled my own version of the login and came up with:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

# Profiling results for each test method are written to tmp/performance.
class BrowsingTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest
   def setup
     login_as
   end
  def test_dashboard
   .....
  end

def login_as
  open_session do |sess|

    user = {}
    user["username"]='fred'
    user["password"]='*****'
    sess.post "/users/sign_in", :user=>user

  end
  end

end
```

And that, at least, ran and gave me metrics. But I see this in the log:

```
 Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-23 10:09:54 -0500
 Processing by DualLoginController#create as HTML
   Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"fred", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Completed 401 Unauthorized in 24ms
  Processing by DualLoginController#new as HTML
 Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"fred", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (79.6ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 277ms (Views: 189.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

 Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-23 10:09:55 -0500
   Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

It seems that the user logged in (maybe) but then wasn't able to get to "/dashboard". The other controllers are the same. If I simply run `rake demo:data:load && rails s` I can login with `fred` and it works fine.

I'm thinking that that the Capybara issue and the database issue is related -- that, for some reason, `rake test:benchmark` isn't running in the Test environment so the data isn't found and Capybara isn't loaded.

Anyone have any thoughts?